# Proof checking : Show that $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right)= \{0\}. $

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Can anyone check my proof please? Thank you.

> Show that $$\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right)= \{0\}.$$

---

Let take an arbitrary $x \in \textbf{R}$ such that $|x|\leq 1/n$  for all $n$ in $\textbf{N}$.
Then $$ -\frac{1}{n}\leq x\leq\frac{1}{n}.$$
We can now say that $$x \in \bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right) .$$
We will now show that $x=0$.
We have: $$ -\frac{1}{n}\leq x \leq\frac{1}{n}.$$
Let's now take the limit $n\to\infty$:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}-\frac{1}{n} \leq x \leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}.$$

$$0\leq x \leq0.$$

By the BigMac theorem, we conclude that $x=0$.

Comment: I've never heard it be called the big mac theorem. LOL.

Comment: Those should be nonstrict inequalities: $\leq$ instead of $<$.  This becomes especially important since only nonstrict inequalities are preserved under limits.

Comment: Haha do you mean squeeze theorem?

Comment: Yes the squeeze theorem lol

Comment: Another approach you could take: For any nonzero $x$, there is $N$ such that $x > \frac{1}{N}$.

Comment: I would prefer to break up the proof into two parts, (i) $0$ is in the intersection (trivial) and (ii) nothing else is. For (ii), suppose $|x|\ne 0$. Then there is a positive integer $N$ such that $\frac{1}{N}\lt |x|$. Now show that $x\not\in (-1/N,1/N)$, and conclude that $x$ is not in the intersection.

Comment: thx guys, I have corrected the mistake

Comment: Ba Da Ba Ba Bah, I'm Lovin' It!

Comment: Hey Big Mac ain't Big Mac, it's *Le* BigMac!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$0 \in (-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n})$ for all $n$, and so $0 \in \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n})$

Suppose for contradiction that there exists some $x \in \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n})$ so that $x \neq 0$. Wlog, suppose $x>0$. Use the archimedean property to show that there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $\frac{1}{N}<x$. Then show that for $n>N$, we have a contradiction.

There is a slight error in your proof, as has been noted in the comment section. Additionally, when you say that $|x|<\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$, how are you justifying this? Really, you're letting $x=0$ anyway, why not begin the proof by showing the intersection to be nonempty?

Comment: Should I started by taking the limite first and then conclude that 0 is in the intersection?

Comment: You need not bother. Use the original definition of an intersection. $x \in A \bigcap B$ iff $x \in A$ and $x \in B$.

Comment: Then look at the first line of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Let's now take the limit $n\to\infty$:$$lim_{n\to\infty}-\frac{1}{n}<x< lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}.$$

This part is incorrect and should be 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}-\frac{1}{n}\leq x\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}$$
which implies that
$$
0\leq x\leq 0
$$
and thus $x=0$.

---

Also, note that $0<x<0$ means $0<x$ and $x<0$, which is a *false* statement whatever $x$ is. I have only seen "Big Mac Theorem" before as a stronger statement of the so called "[Hamburger's Theorem](https://www.haverford.edu/sites/default/files/Department/Math/Colloquium2012-04-09Daughton.pdf)".

Comment: thx , I have corrected the mistake.

Comment: Ba Da Ba Ba Bah, I'm Lovin' It!